# DataRow[] dr = fromTable.Select(expr); failes if expr contains backslash

Tags: c#, datatable

given is a small `DaTaTable`, containing a column `"Measurement File"`, it contains the path to the measurementfiles. A second column should show some values evaluated from those files.

To find the corresponding rows I wrote a small method

```
public static DataRow[] SelectRows(DataTable fromTable,string ColName,string CellContent)
{
    expr = ((ColName.Contains(" ")) ? "'" + ColName + "'" : ColName) + " = '" + CellContent + "'";
    return fromTable.Select(expr);
}
```

This fails, if expr  contains backslashes, which of course occur in paths...
the problem is, that the WPF Shows just one backslash, the debugger shows them with their escape sequence

I tried the @literal, but I think I did in a wrong way.
But what me really confuses is following statment:

```
fromTable.Rows[0][2]==CellContent
```

it evaluates to True if the contents are identically (otherwise to false)

So I'm doing a beginners error, but I don't see it.

Comment: the debugger adds a \ so you can see what it is  please add example string (and note if necessary whether the string is the string or what you see in the debugger so for examlple c:\ shows as c:\\ in the debugger

Comment: when you say "fails", do you mean, fails to return anything or error? why don't you put breakpoint at `return` and post here contents of `expr`? you second "thing" seem working as designed

Comment: Good morning,
the method itself:
        public static DataRow[] SelectRows(DataTable fromTable,string ColName,string CellContent)
            {
            DataRow[] dr;
            string expr = "";
            expr = ((ColName.Contains(" ")) ? "'" + ColName + "'" : ColName) + " = '" + CellContent + "'";
            dr = fromTable.Select(expr);
            try { return dr; }
            catch ( Exception ex)
                {
                log(ex.Message, Log_Level.ERROR);
                return null;
                }
            }

Comment: it works fine for:
expr
"bez = 'Manufacturer'"
dr
{System.Data.DataRow[1]}
    [0]: {System.Data.DataRow}

Comment: Sorry for misstyping and missusing...I'll work on it

the failure raises for this:
"'Measurement File' = 'I:\\A-D\\Batt-Zelle\\01_Zelldaten\\xxxxxxxx\\yyyyyyyyy\\Messungen\\No.19\\zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz zzzzzzzzzzzz.57\\TE_0000002927.DB'"

the result of the DataTable.select(expr) is Empty e.g. length=0


fromTable.Rows[0][2] shows
"I:\\A-D\\Batt-Zelle\\01_Zelldaten\\xxxxxxxx\\yyyyyyyyy\\Messungen\\No.19\\zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz zzzzzzzzzzzz.57\\TE_0000002927.DB"


and the test 

fromTable.Rows[0][2]==CellContent

results as true